# limit order placed at wrong price pine script

Tags: pine-script

I tried to use a simple CCI as long and short entries. And for long entries I would like to have limit order of 1% less than the trigger price. However, the actual price is very different from the trigger price without the limit order.  For instance, if the buy entry price is 100(using code without limit order), the buying price with limit order should be 99, but in reality it's 92.3. What I did wrong?

```
//@version=5
strategy(title='test', overlay=false, pyramiding=0)

///CCI Source Code///
length = input.int(200, minval=1)
src = close
ma = ta.sma(src, length)
cci = (src - ma) / (0.015 * ta.dev(src, length))
plot(cci, "CCI", color=color.blue)

///long/short entry///
if cci > 0
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, limit=close * 0.99)
if cci < 0
    strategy.cancel("Long")
if cci < 0
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)


Thanks ahead for your help!
```

Comment: maybe because the new bar open is 92.3?

Comment: I use the strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long) as comparison group. When the trigger price is 100, the strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, limit=close * 0.99) price should be 99. But in reality it's not, don't know why. And instead of using "cci > 0" as condition, if I use ta.crossover(ema20, ema50), the result is correct. If I use ema20 > ema50, the result is not correct. So maybe it's value comparison's problem. Just don't know the reason why and logic behind and how to correct this.

Comment: Do you have the screenshot demonstrating the issue? What ticker & TF?